# Can FasterXML Jackson map mixed list child elements

Tags: jackson, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

Using the object mapper feature of FasterXML Jackson, I would like to parse this XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
  <category name="A">
    <category name="B">
      <setting type="Float">
        <name>Bar</name>
      </setting>
    </category>
    <setting type="Float">
      <name>Foo</name>
    </setting>
    <category name="C">
      <setting type="Float">
        <name>Baz</name>
      </setting>
    </category>
  </category>
</categories>
```

using the following Scala code:

```
case class Categories(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "category") categories: List[Category])
case class Category(name: String, @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "category") categories: List[Category], @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "setting") settings: List[Setting])
case class Setting(`type`: String, name: String)

val xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
xmlMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false)

val categories = xmlMapper.readValue(snippet, classOf[Categories])
println(categories)
// Categories(List(Category(A,List(Category(C,null,List(Setting(Float,Baz)))),List(Setting(Float,Foo)))))
```

I can see that Category B is missing from the result. If I change the order and move `setting` after the categories, it works as intended.

```
// Categories(List(Category(A,List(Category(B,null,List(Setting(Float,Bar))), Category(C,null,List(Setting(Float,Baz)))),List(Setting(Float,Foo)))))

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
  <category name="A">
    <category name="B">
      <setting type="Float">
        <name>Bar</name>
      </setting>
    </category>
    <category name="C">
      <setting type="Float">
        <name>Baz</name>
      </setting>
    </category>
    <setting type="Float">
      <name>Foo</name>
    </setting>
  </category>
</categories>
```

So it appears to be skipping elements if child list are mixed together. Is there a property I can set on the Mapper to fix this?